# Temporary file path using swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

How to get a unique temporary file path using Swift/Cocoa on OS X?
Cocoa does not seem to provide a function for this, only `NSTemporaryDirectory()` which returns the path of the temporary directory. Using the BSD `mktemp` function requires a mutable C-string as argument.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a possible method to use `mkstemp()` from **Swift 3** and later. `URL` methods
are used to convert between `URL` instances and C strings representing the file system path:

```
// The template string:
let template = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("file.XXXXXX") as NSURL

// Fill buffer with a C string representing the local file system path. 
var buffer = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: Int(PATH_MAX))
template.getFileSystemRepresentation(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)

// Create unique file name (and open file):
let fd = mkstemp(&buffer)
if fd != -1 {

    // Create URL from file system string:
    let url = URL(fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation: buffer, isDirectory: false, relativeTo: nil)
    print(url.path)

} else {
    print("Error: " + String(cString: strerror(errno)))
}
```

---

**Older code for Swift 2:**

```
// The template string:
let template = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.XXXXXX")

// Fill buffer with a C string representing the local file system path. 
var buffer = [Int8](count: Int(PATH_MAX), repeatedValue: 0)
template.getFileSystemRepresentation(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)

// Create unique file name (and open file):
let fd = mkstemp(&buffer)
if fd != -1 {

    // Create URL from file system string:
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation: buffer, isDirectory: false, relativeToURL: nil)
    print(url.path!)

} else {
    print("Error: " + String(strerror(errno)))
}
```

Comment: Nice. I think you should use `mkstemp` as the example instead of `mktemp` because it's generally safer.

Comment: It is also needed to `close` the file descriptor `fd` from `mkstemp`?

Comment: @tmlen: Yes, otherwise you have a file descriptor leak. Alternatively, create a file handle with `let fh = NSFileHandle(fileDescriptor: fd, closeOnDealloc: true)` to transfer the ownership. The fd will be closed when the file handle is deallocated.

Answer (score 42):

Apple has been trying to move away from path-as-string and into `NSURL`. Here's one way:

**Swift 3:**

```
let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let fileName = NSUUID().uuidString

// This returns a URL? even though it is an NSURL class method
let fullURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: [directory, fileName])
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let fileName = NSUUID().UUIDString

let fullURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents([directory, fileName])
```

Answer (score 21):

Although `NSTemporaryDirectory()` does indeed return a temporary directory path for the current user, [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409211-nstemporarydirectory) includes the following caveat:

> See the [`FileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) method [`url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url) for the preferred means of finding the correct temporary directory.

Following that link, we are presented with the following:

> You can use this method to create a new temporary directory. To do so, specify [`FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.itemReplacementDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory/itemreplacementdirectory) for the `directory` parameter, [`userDomainMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdomainmask/1408037-userdomainmask) for the `domain` parameter, and a URL for the `url` parameter which determines the volume of the returned URL.
>
> For example, the following code results in a new temporary directory with a path in the form of `/private/var/folders/d0/h37cw8ns3h1bfr_2gnwq2yyc0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/Untitled/`:
>
> ```
> let desktop = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jappleseed/Desktop/")
>
> do {
>    let temporaryDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(
>        for: .itemReplacementDirectory,
>        in: .userDomainMask,
>        appropriateFor: desktop,
>        create: true
>    )
>
>    print(temporaryDirectory)
> } catch {
>    // Handle the error.
> }
> ```

(Note the the `create` parameter is ignored when creating a temporary directory.)

So what exactly is the difference between these two approaches? Well, here's what I get when I call the two different methods from the [Swift REPL](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=18):

```
1> import Foundation

2> NSTemporaryDirectory() 
$R0: String = "/var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/"

3> let desktop = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/chris/Desktop/") 
desktop: URL = "file:///Users/chris/Desktop/"

4> let temporaryDirectory = try FileManager.default.url( 
5.     for: .itemReplacementDirectory, 
6.     in: .userDomainMask, 
7.     appropriateFor: desktop, 
8.     create: true 
9. )
temporaryDirectory: URL = "file:///var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20repl_swift)/"
```

It appears that `NSTemporaryDirectory()` will always return *the* temporary directory path for the current user whereas `FileManager`'s `url(for:appropriateFor:create)` will return a *new* temporary subdirectory each time it is called. For example, here are the directories returned by consecutive calls to `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` from the Swift REPL:

- `file:///var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20repl_swift)/`
- `file:///var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20repl_swift%202)/`
- `file:///var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20repl_swift%203)/`

And here are the directories returned by consecutive calls to the same method from a Swift Playground:

- `file:///var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20Xcode)/`
- `file:///var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20Xcode%202)/`
- `file:///var/folders/n_/0_9q7d2d1ls5v9kx599y_tj00000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20Xcode%203)/`

The [NSHipster article on temporary files](http://nshipster.com/nstemporarydirectory/) seems to suggest that the `FileManager` method `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` is intended to be used when staging a file to be moved to a more permanent location (such as the user's desktop in the example above), but I don't see why it couldn't also be used to simply get a unique subdirectory that will automatically be removed when you're done with it and where you shouldn't have to worry about files getting accidentally clobbered by other processes writing to the same temporary directory.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Answers like this make SO *the* place to get answers.

Comment: @mojuba Glad you found it helpful! ☺️

Answer (score 9):

A Swift 3 one-liner inspired by the [UUID based Swift 2 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32657777/504931):

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
```

Answer (score 7):

FileManager extension in Swift to get a temporary file URL. You can pass your own file name and extension, if needed.

```
public extension FileManager {

    func temporaryFileURL(fileName: String = UUID().uuidString) -> URL? {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryFileURL()
let tempJPG = FileManager.default.temporaryFileURL(fileName: "temp.jpg")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a GUID (Globally Unique Identifier):

```
let directory :NSString = "directory"
let randomName = NSProcessInfo().globallyUniqueString
let path = directory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(randomName)
```

> directory/3B635E49-813A-4324-B4B8-56279B42BEAB-36687-0002D962615DAE5F

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea of this article: [NSTemporary​Directory - NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nstemporarydirectory/)

This uses the `NSTemporaryDirectory()` for the temporary folder and `ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString` to generate a unique string.

Swift 4:

```
func uniqueTempFolderURL() -> URL
{
    let folderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(folderName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift3

I came here looking for something like [boost::filesystem::unique_path()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#unique_path)

So I made this extension to the URL class.

```
extension URL {
    func appendingUniquePathComponent(pathExtension: String? = nil) -> URL {
        var pathComponent = UUID().uuidString
        if let pathExtension = pathExtension {
            pathComponent += ".\(pathExtension)"
        }
        return appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
let url0 = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/some/dir")
let url1 = url0.appendingUniquePathComponent(pathExtension: "jpg")
print("url1: \(url1)")
// url1: file:///tmp/some/dir/936324FF-EEDB-410E-AD09-E24D5EB4A24F.jpg
```

Comment: Add here `NSTemporaryDirectory()` and this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

If your project target on newer platform:

## macOS 13.0, iOS 16.0

```swift
URL.temporaryDirectory.appending(path:UUID().uuidString, directoryHint: .notDirectory)
```

or you can create an more compatible extension as following:

## Backward Compatible Version

```swift
extension URL {
    static var compatibleTemporary: Self {
        if #available(macOS 13.0, iOS 16.0, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0, *) {
            URL.temporaryDirectory
        } else {
            URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is a compatible version of appending function:

```swift
extension URL {
    func compatibleAppending(path: String, isDirectory: Bool? = nil) -> URL {
        if #available(macOS 13.0, iOS 16.0, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0, *) {
            var hint: DirectoryHint = .inferFromPath
            if let isDirectory = isDirectory {
                hint = isDirectory ? .isDirectory : .notDirectory
            }
            return appending(path: path, directoryHint: hint)
        } else {
            if let isDirectory = isDirectory {
                return URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: isDirectory)
            }
            return URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```swift
URL.compitableTemporary.compitableAppending(path: UUID().uuidString)
```

Answer (score -1):

just my two cents, comparing iOS and MacOS (sandboxed)

code:

```
let tmp_path1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
let tmp_path2 = NSTemporaryDirectory()

print("\n--\n", tmp_path1!, "\n", tmp_path2)
```

we got:

```
> -- MacOs /Users/ingconti/Library/Containers/com.ingconti.ZipArchiveDebugAppMacOs/Data/Library/Caches
> /var/folders/40/8w6s0bsn4d55d9cjf16sjz440000gp/T/com.ingconti.ZipArchiveDebugAppMacOs/
> 
> 
> iOS simulator 
> /Users/ingconti/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AC9CBFC-5535-4213-9394-523DA82B4637/data/Containers/Data/Application/82EFDDFA-D541-4791-B76F-D754116F43C9/Library/Caches
> /Users/ingconti/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AC9CBFC-5535-4213-9394-523DA82B4637/data/Containers/Data/Application/82EFDDFA-D541-4791-B76F-D754116F43C9/tmp/
> 
> iOS 
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F9EA2D1-7CCD-48B3-85C1-957FDF0D1925/Library/Caches
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F9EA2D1-7CCD-48B3-85C1-957FDF0D1925/tmp/
> 
> or something similar on Your machine
```

to point out:
it's better leave iOS / macOS use and reclaim space on its own, so I honestly prefer to stick with built in solution.

If temporary means "delete when no need" better lave apple do so.
If You start build your own logic:
a) you have to remember to claim space manually
b) apple APIS have better chances to remain stable, you solution building a folder by hand can stop working (it' what happened to an macOS App if mine when sandbox came out)

IF you need ad UNIQUE name, si very different, in these case you can use proposed solution adding for example:

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

Comment: While this info may be useful, it makes no attempt to answer the question. The question is asking how to generate a temporary file path, not how to access a folder. The question even states that `NSTemporaryDirectory()` is not what is wanted.

Comment: I DO know what is asked, I simply point out NO NEED. I will add a note.

Comment: Just read your update. Only the last paragraph applies to the question. But that was covered in the other answers so there doesn't seem to be any need for this answer.