# Which file system directory should I use to store files?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteraction

I just read through this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) about ios file system. However, I still unable to decide how to properly store files in my app.

My app basically does the following.

- display all sorts of files from the net. (docx, pdf, video, images, etc)
- user can choose to save offline for the above files.

From the link, I think I have 3 directory choices.

- Documents/ (recommended for user-generated or cannot be downloaded)
- tmp/ (after done with files, should be deleted)
- Library/caches (system will delete, but caches store longer than tmp)

So, my questions are,

- where should I put if the user choose to save offline?
- where should I put if the user decided not to save offline? 
  I am using `UIDocumentInteractionController`

Also, I am a bit confused between cashes and tmp.

It would be nice if you can provide me sample code or link to tutorial blogs. Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the offline function, what else do you do with the files?

Comment: **would appreciate, if you can provide me sample code.** -> This is not a coding service. You need to write your own code.

Comment: I just need to display them, the app is about, student viewing learning materials created by lecturers.

Comment: I am not asking to code for me, I am just saying it would be nice if you provide me sample codes, I just want to know the correct choice of directory to store my files

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html it has all information you need there. You won’t get any answer more detailed than the link you already found.

Comment: thanks @LeoDabus, I found the links you provided useful!

Comment: @KyawHtetSoe you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You should store downloaded files in /Documents if you want to display them in future. You should provide an option to delete them.

There is two well-written library to reduce your effort.

https://github.com/JohnSundell/Files by John Sundell

https://github.com/sketchytech/SwiftFiles by Anthony Levings

Answer (score 0):

For offline, you should store them in the `Documents` folder so that the system won't delete them automatically.

If there is no other use of the file, you should not download them at all.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but using UIDocumentInteractionController to display .ppt and .docx required the files is locally stored. If there are just videos, and pdf, I can use UIWebView and AVPlayer and no need to download, But .ppt, .docx, I need to save temporarily

Comment: For temporary storage https://stackoverflow.com/a/32657777/1433612